# In IE6, and using divs, how to split entire page into two columns, left div with static width and right with elastic width?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I don't know if what am asking for is even possible in IE6, but here goes:  I am working on a page layout and want to split the body into two container divs. I want to give the left div a fixed width of 200px; while making the right div elastic along the page's width.  The right div's left border must be touching the left div's right border to make things clearer i made a diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/UhdHu/

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="col_1">
            <p>column 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col_2">
            <p>column 2</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
     height:100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     background-color:#000000;
}
#col_1 {
     height:100%;
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     width:200px;
     padding:10px;
     background-color:#DBDBDB;
}
#col_2 {
     height:100%;
     margin-top:0px;
     margin-right:0px;
     margin-left:220px;
     padding:10px;
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

sourced from: http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-box-model/1-column-fixed-1-column-fluid.html

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<html style="height:100%">
<body style="height:100%;margin:0px;">
  <div style="position:absolute;left:0;right:0;z-index:1000;height:100%;width:200px;background-color:red;">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div style="height:100%;width:100%;">
    <div style="padding-left:200px;background-color:blue;height:100%">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

here it is online: http://milkish.com/test/ie6.html
check it with netrender: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td width="200px">
           <!-- area1 -->

      </td
      <td>
           <!-- area2 -->

      </td>
   </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?